# Delay dev-sda2.device

Tags: boot

What is this?

```
 17.537s dev-sda2.device
```

systemd-analyze blame

```
     18.346s dev-sda2.device
     17.472s systemd-journal-flush.service
     16.439s configure-printer@usb-002-004.service
     12.998s dev-loop3.device
     12.974s dev-loop4.device
     12.941s dev-loop5.device
     12.934s dev-loop1.device
     12.910s dev-loop0.device
     12.882s dev-loop2.device
     11.276s systemd-udevd.service
      9.327s configure-printer@usb-002-005.service
      6.983s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.396s apt-daily-upgrade.service
      3.819s udisks2.service
      3.710s NetworkManager.service
      3.630s snapd.service
      3.331s apt-daily.service
      3.106s accounts-daemon.service
      3.046s ModemManager.service
      2.951s plymouth-start.service
      2.678s grub-common.service
      2.364s snap-ubuntu\x2dmate\x2dwelcome-169.mount
      2.342s snap-core-4917.mount

    mount: /: /dev/sda2 already mounted on /.
```

I would like to delay it until after my computer has booted up to speed up my boot time.

Comment: I understand that it is output of `systemd-analyze blame`, but could you please include this information in question. Also please include output of `mount` command. `dev-sda2.device` may correspond to root partition or home partition, they need time to be mounted and checked for errors with `fsck` (like `CHKDSK` in windows). And why you opened new question, based on [previous one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057040/startup-time-discrepancy)?

Comment: @NObert My question is not based on a previous one. It's a totally different issue.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/948748/what-is-dev-sda-device-in-systemd-analyze-can-i-disable-it as to what `dev-sda2.device` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delay this until after booting.

`sda2` is your Root Partition ("/") so that means this device is the Root of your Entire OS.

The Task that takes so long is mounting this Partition so it can be used.

But it seems that this takes too long, it could be a Driver/Partition Failure (errors shown with fsck ( @N0rbert ) ), slow HDD, something else. We don't have enough information to help for that.

Comment: What additional info do you need?